# How do we find a Taylor series for complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose I wanted to find a Taylor series for $f(z)=\sin(z)$ centered at $0$ for example.

I know for $f(x)=\sin(x)$ we can use the formula $$\sum_{n=0} ^ {\infty} \frac {f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} \, (x-a)^{n}$$ to find $$f(x)=\sin\left( x \right) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!}+...$$ but to find a similar series for $\sin(z)$ I am stuck. Is there some kind of analogous formula for finding a Taylor series for complex valued functions? If so what kind of properties would $f(z)$ need to ensure it has a Taylor series representation?

Here is what I tried so far:

$$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$ then using (definition of $e^z$?) we have $$\sin(z)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-iz)^n}{n!}\right)$$ but I'm not sure if this is correct at all.

Could anyone help clear this up for me?

Comment: Isn't the taylor series of $\sin(x)$ defined over $\mathbb{C}$ because $\sin(x)$ is entire?

Comment: I don't understand your comment sorry.

Comment: See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html).

Comment: So we can just use the formula $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0} ^ {\infty} (z-z_0)^n \frac {f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}$$ to find $\sin (z)$? Can I also ask if my method above is correct anyway or not?